# How to get the vertex position after applying translate, rotate and scale to geometry using three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, geometry, transform

I have been playing with three.js.

What my objective is to create a curve in the scene and apply some transform to it.  The function is to create the line is:

```
var random_degree = Math.round(Math.rand() * 180);
var tmp = [
    new THREE.Vector3(-5, 0, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 5),
    new THREE.Vector3(5, 0, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -5),
];
var canvasW = window.innerWidth;
var canvasH = window.innerHeight;
// so the initial curve is a circle on x-z plain.

function get_line_geo() {
    var angle = (random_degree + 1 * 0.25) % 360 * (Math.PI / 180);
    var tx = Math.cos(angle) * canvasW * 0.25;
    angle = (random_degree + 1 * 0.3) % 360 * (Math.PI / 180);
    var ty = Math.sin(angle) * canvasH * 0.25;

    var curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(tmp);
    curve.closed = true;

    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices = curve.getPoints(300);
    console.log(geometry.vertices[0].x + ' ' +geometry.vertices[0].y + ' ' +geometry.vertices[0].z);
    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial();
    var curveObject = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
    curveObject.translateX((canvasW - margin * 2) / 2 + tx);
    curveObject.translateY((canvasH - margin * 2) / 2 + ty);
    curveObject.translateZ((canvasH - margin * 2) / 2 + ty);

    curveObject.rotation.x = ((random_degree + 1 * 0.25) % 360) * Math.PI / 180;
    curveObject.rotation.y = ((random_degree + 1 * 0.25) % 360) * Math.PI / 180;
    curveObject.rotation.z = ((random_degree + 1 * 0.25) % 360) * Math.PI / 180;

   curveObject.scale.x = 10;
   curveObject.scale.y = 10;
   curveObject.scale.z = 10;

   console.log(curveObject.geometry.vertices[0].x + ' ' +curveObject.geometry.vertices[0].y + ' ' +curveObject.geometry.vertices[0].z);

   return curveObject;
}
```

I checked the vertices positions by using `console.log()`, they did not change in the geometry context. So is there any method I can calculate the new positions for these vertices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not apply transforms to the *geometry*. You applied transforms to the *object*.

It is a good idea to study the source code of the methods you are using so you understand what they are doing. You will learn a lot that way.

After modifying the `position`, `rotation`, or `scale` properties of the object, you need to call

```
curveObject.updateMatrix();
```

Then do this:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();

vector.copy( curveObject.geometry.vertices[ 0 ] );

vector.applyMatrix4( curveObject.matrix );

console.log( vector );
```

three.js r.75

Comment: Great, it helped me a lot. The only thing is in the most recent version of three.js, the applyMatrix for verctor3 has been updated to two method: 1. applyMatrix3 and 2 applyMatrix4. And I think it is r75. Please refer http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Math/Vector3. Anyway I will mark it as an answer. And from what I had tested, the applyMatrix4 is what I want.

Comment: Oops. Typo. Corrected. Thanks.